# search a string only inside a function definetion

Tags: perl, unix, awk, sed, grep

Is there any way to search a string only inside a function definition.
I mean to say suppose there is a c program file a.c , in which there is definition of several functions are present , but i want output of search only when that string present inside specific function ( lets say do_something()) definition, is there any way to search string like that, from command prompt?
for example , for following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void f(int n,
         int j,
         int k)
{
   printf("name is is pankaj ");
   printf("name is is kumar ");
   printf("name is is mayank ");
}
int main()
{
   printf("name is is pankaj ");
   return 0;
}
```

for above program, I want only one occurrence of pankaj which is present in function f(), I don't want pankaj present in main function as output of search.
Please ignore any semantic or syntax error in program , my query is only for search of a string in program.

Comment: By coding, what have you tried?

Comment: i have not tried anything , was just curious to know, like if i do grep "kumar" a.c than it will give all occurance of kumar in a.c , is there any way with mix of regular expressing so that i can force my grep to look only inside a function definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, try this:

```
$0 ~ fun {
    count = 1
    while (! ($0 ~ /{/))
        getline
    getline
}   

count > 0 {
    if ($0 ~ /{/)
        count++
    if ($0 ~ /}/)
        count--
    if ($0 ~ query)
        print FILENAME ": l" FNR ". " $0
}
```

And invoke the script like this:

```
awk -v query="pankaj" -v fun="void f[(]" -f script.awk inputfile.java
```

Where `query` is the string to search and `fun` the regex for the function name.

This script counts `{` and `}` to see when we leave the function and should print the line if a match is found.

Edit: you may want to extend the regex for counting brackets, perhaps an extra check to see if they aren't placed in comments is required (although you'd never do that).

Comment: I have tried it in the program given in question (edited the Q just now), but its not working.

Comment: Right, forgot about multi-line functions. Try now.

Comment: just one more thing , what if there is more than 1 file , say inputfile1.java and inputfile2.java , in that case , will following command work:       awk -v query="pankaj" -v fun="void f[(]" -f script.awk inputfile1.java inputfile2.java

Comment: Yes you can, I will update the script to print the file name as well. You could also do `awk ... script.awk *.java`  to apply it to all java files in the current directory. You can even include more files bij adding them at the end of the command. `../*.java src/*.c` for example also searches all java files in the parent directory and even c files in a directory called src.

Comment: My pleasure, you can always thank me by upvoting if you deemed it a quality answer.

Comment: I upvoted you , but sombody gave you -1 before , so i was able to make it 0 only :)